# SQL query to show updated account balances

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have two tables, [Party] and [Invoice], in an Access database. I want to summarize all party balances. Here is my query so far:

```
select 
    Party.AccountCode,
    Party.AccountDescription,
    OpeningBalance+sum(invoiceAmount) as balance,
    invoiceDate 
from Party,Inovoice 
where party.accountCode=Inovice.AccountCode 
    and invoiceDate>=01-01-2013 
    and invoiceDate<=30-06-2013
group by 
    Party.AccountCode,
    Party.AccountDescription,
    invoiceDate
```

This query returns the balance for only the two parties that appear in the [Invoice] table: TOM and JHONS. I want to display the balance for all 4 parties:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use two queries. The first to calculate the total invoice amount and the second for the party balances

qrySumInvoiceAmounts:

```
SELECT 
AccountCode
sum(invoiceAmount) as InvoiceBalance,
FROM Invoice    
group by 
AccountCode,
WHERE invoiceDate>= #01-01-2013#
and invoiceDate<= #30-06-2013#
```

qryPartyBalance:

```
SELECT
Party.AccountCode,
Party.AccountDescription,
OpeningBalance + InvoiceBalance,
from Party LEFT JOIN qrySumInvoiceAmounts
ON party.accountCode=qrySumInvoiceAmounts.AccountCode
```

Comment: this query show an error you tried to that does not inculde specified expersion openingBalance+sum(invoiceAmount) as a part of agregate function

Comment: Query Working but it does not bring any results for an account without an invoice

Comment: Try changing sum(invoiceAmount) to nz(sum(invoiceAmount),0)

Comment: hi Emett I  try to chage sum(invoiceAmount) to nz(sum(invoiceAmount),0)  but no success it show same result only display who have record in invoice table

Comment: I fixed the query. See above

Comment: RE: `WHERE ... invoiceDate<= #30-06-2013#` - Beware of ambiguous date formats inside date literals. `#yyyy-mm-dd#` is a much safer choice.

Comment: hi Emett these Two Queries Return Following Result AccountCode 1001 TOM Balance 330,AccountCode 1002 ADAM Balance 0,AccountCode 1003 jhons Balance 7860,,AccountCode 1004 Belly Balance 0  it was not get opening balance ADAM ,Adam Have OpeningBalance 3000 please see pic above

Comment: Use Nz() function: nz(InvoiceBalance,0)